# Verifying what strings inside all localizable.strings files are obsolete

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have project that has several years. Over the time, the app has been modified, some classes added, some removed, etc. This app is localized in 5 languages.

Is there a way to scan all `localizable.strings` files and detect which strings inside these files are not used anymore in the project?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way! Basically, you have to dump the .strings using commands and then compare them to acceptable versions. For more details, see here: [iphone - cleaning the Localizable.strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442142/iphone-cleaning-the-localizable-strings)