# How to maintain/clean localized strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a rather huge strings file with about 600 strings in it. A couple of developers just dumped their strings into it for every module they wrote. There are a lot of strings there that are no longer used, or had been replaced. Also some more general error messages and such exist in several varieties and should be replaced by just one.

I went through 50 or so by select, copy-paste into search and see if they are still used in code... eclipse/lint does that for me, xcode 5 (still) doesnt seem to have that feature.

Now i found a plugin (LIN) that makes selecting/autocompleting of strings easier but i still have about 600 unchecked strings.

Only ONE language exists right now but a second is about to come, so i want to clean up the mess BEFORE that.

I have read

[iphone - cleaning the Localizable.strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442142/iphone-cleaning-the-localizable-strings)

but find the answer very impractical

**/edit**

What strategies are there that do the work and just show me the results ?! I feel like in the stone age of IDEs

Comment: Did you ever find answer for this?

Comment: not really, it is one of the massive flaws of xcode. I think i just searched for those strings that looked outdated and if i found no occurence, i deleted them. Still leaves a bad taste as it did happen, that strings were used but didnt show up for silly reasons

Comment: Did you do it manually, or with some script? If you have that script, can you share it?

Comment: manually, maybe half an hour until i got annoyed.

Answer (score 6):

I dont know if you still have this problem, but [AppCode IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) shows you the strings which are not in use and lets you safe delete it (remove it from all your language files).

[image: screenshot_of_appcode]

Comment: I wonder why Xcode 9 doesn't support similar string management features.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool to make this. But eventually didn't use it. Maybe it helps you o someone.

https://github.com/ijoshsmith/abandoned-strings